# PhoneGap communication with external server

Tags: php, javascript, json, rest, cordova

I am developing a number of pet projects with PhoneGap and I was interested as to if anyone could recommend the best way to securely send data from the app to a server, and vice versa.

I'm logging the user in with Facebook, with their access_token in localStorage so it will persist, but I'm going to need to hit the server to create a profile, collect data to display in-app, etc..

I have considered a JSON service that auth's against an encrypted Facebook UID, or a digest auth based REST service. Any ideas on what the "proper" way to do this would be?

Comment: The rightest way would just be over https with some form of authentication on your server end =)

Comment: What do u think? Digest?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using SSL, I find its way less hassle that trying to hash something yourself. If you are not using SSL you can't prevent a man in the middle attack...maybe im wrong here, or lazy, probably both...

Comment: The data wouldn't be sensitive enough for me to install a SSL. It's pretty non-consequential data, I just want to have the app be able to access this api. Plus with SSL, I would still have to Auth the request if I wanted to keep miscreants out, right?